# Embedding Instagram reels without black bars

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

When I am using the Instagram embedding code for reels, i get black bars left/right of the video inside the container.

I tried to manipulate height/width in the embedding code, however that only targets the container, black bars remain. Any ideas on how to get rid of the unnecessary black bars?